# website looks different in mozilla firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have been coding a website for a friend closely to his screenshot he send me.
I was coding it, while viewing in chrome, but then i realized the position of the `section` is messed up in mozilla firefox.

how can I fix it, so it looks fine in both browsers?

here is the link to it so i dont have to paste all the code: http://pgw10eu.url.ph/more/des/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the height of the active `li`. Check `padding-bottom` in `nav li.active`. You have it set to 10px but if you set it to 8px it's okay.

If your browser window is narrow in FF then you see a small gap between "Page 2" - "Page 6" between the `nav` bar and the `section`. "Page 1" actually touches the section.

If the browser window is wide then the `section` can float up to touch the `nav` but the height of the active `li` pushes it to the right.

Comment: i found it out for my self as said in my answer above. still giving you the correct answer mark.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found out, that chrome and firefox have different padding sizes (even though the number is the same) I just have to add firefox specific padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by using Chrome's and Firefox's built-in developer tools.

Just inspect the HTML elements and compare their sizes (margins, etc.).
You should be able to find the difference that way.

You can change the CSS properties on-the-fly with the developer tools
and correct your source code later.

Comment: i know this, but when i change something in firefox it goes the wrong way in chrome also. so confusing.